# PC start error. How to solve it?

Tags: windows-error-reporting

So whenever I turn on my PC and log in I get this error:

> There was a problem starting c /users/appdata/local/total/Virtual/Bin/TotalVirtual.dll"

Any ideas what this might be guys?

Comment: Have you tried running a scan for virusses and malware?

Comment: Run `msconfig` and remove the Startup entry for that path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the program was? If so, did you uninstall the program or delete it?

If you don't know what it is, then do virus scans and malware scans, like LPChip suggests.

If a simple program, you might be able to uncheck it from the start up in `msconfig` like Steven suggests.

Sometimes those things don't work. When those fail, I recommend using [HiJackThis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/)  this program can help you remove all sorts of stuff that starts when your computer start. You need to be careful with what you are removing though, otherwise you may have to reinstall programs you do want running on the computer.